# How can I destroy (clear) a session php?

Tags: php, arrays, session, web

```
if (isset($_POST['clear'])) {
      session_unset($_SESSION['dataRow']);
      session_unset($_SESSION['dataColumn']);
      session_destroy();
      echo ' Data has been deleted. ';
}
```

[image]

Comment: By using `session_destroy()` as in your code.

Comment: do you have `session_start()` somewhere in your code ?

Answer (score 4):

Unset will destroy a particular session variable while session_destroy() will destroy all the session data for that user.

It depends on your application how to use it, just keep this in mind:

```
unset($_SESSION['name']); // will delete just the name data

session_destroy(); // will delete ALL data associated with that user.
```